# PHP and SQLite No such file or directory?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm completely new to database and I'm trying to get my login page to check the database for username and password. I'm getting this error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/checklogin.php on line 11
cannot connect

Running XAMPP and I tried modifying the php.ini file and also tried connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I'm not sure why it's doing this. Also where should my test.db file be? In the  same directory as the index.html?

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="test"; // Mysql username 
$password="test"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Does this work also?

```
 function getConnected($host,$username,$password,$db_name) 
 {
 $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

 if($mysqli->connect_error) 
  die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

 return $mysqli;
 }

 $mysqli = getConnected('localhost','user','password','database');
```

Comment: do you want mysql or sqlite? The title says sqlite, but I only see mysql functions.

Comment: btw, localhost and 127.0.0.1 are the same thing.

Comment: If you are trying to use an sqlite database through the mysql interface, that most certainly won't work.

Comment: @Tim I wanted sqlite, I got that generic code from a mysql file that's probably why. Sorry I'm not too familiar with either of them so I'm trying to learn as I go. I have a test.db, not sure if I set it up correctly but if I could figure the connecting part of it out I could figure out the rest of the db easily.

I  thought mysql and sqlite functions were the same but I guess it might be only some?

Comment: sqlite has its own functions. There are normally equivalents, but not necessarily. The PHP manual is a big help. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php

Comment: Oh no, I'm not trying to access a SQLite database through MySQL interface, I'm trying to change everything to SQLite. Am I still able to modify this file accordingly to SQLite or will that give it issues?

Comment: ok... so you have mysql code(above) and you want to convert it to use sqlite interface instead?

Comment: Yes I want to use it all on SQLite, is the code above modifiable to SQLite?

Comment: Should be. Only difference is instead of connecting to an sqlite database you open it. and the other functions have different names and the SQL syntax is sometimes different,

Comment: This question might be a bit dumb but does it matter where my test.db file is at in order for the checklogin to access it?

Comment: It only has to be in an accessible directory. If you want to be able to modify it, it has to have write permissions. If it is in a different directory than your source, you have to give the right path to the open command.

Answer (score 0):

**Connecting to SQLite**

It doesn't looks like your connecting to a sqlite database, since you haven't specified the database file's path. Try this small script to have a more concise way to connect to your db.

```
class Db {

    private $config;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = array(
            'path' => 'path/to/your/database.sqlite'
        );

        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $connectionQuery = 'sqlite:' .$this->config['path'];

        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO($connectionQuery);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }

}

$db = new DB();
```

**Database path**

Change this *'path/to/your/database.sqlite'* to whatever path you like.

**Retrieving connection handle**

Just use *$db->getConnection()* to access it.

Comment: Why downvote? He's asking for a solution, to connect to his sqlite database.

Comment: Not precisely. They were confused and you'probably didn't read closely enough. They have database code using the `mysqli` interface and they would like to convert it to use the `sqlite` interface, but don't know how. This information is factually correct, but not directly germane to the question. You could easily modify it to answer the question directly. If you did so, you might get an upvote from me.